# Create array of arrays in jython for java interop

Tags: java, arrays, jython

How to create java array of arrays?

I am able to create one dimensional array using

```
jarray.zeros(10, Object)
```

I am trying to create outer array with

```
jarray.zeros(2, Array)
```

But I got

> NameError: name 'Array' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I have is to create list and convert it:

```
list = []
for x in range(0,2):
    list.append([None] * 10)
javaArray = jarray.array(list, Class.forName('[Ljava.lang.Object;')))
```